# Building MinGW with Mingw-builds fails

Tags: c++, build, mingw-w64, gcc10

I have been building mingw-w64 using mingw-builds (https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds) successfully for a long time. Now I wanted to build g++ 10.3, but somehow it does not work anymore. I have found no related questions and I am not aware of any mailing list dealing with such issues.

I am working with mingw-builds commit 6b7989789154e91110585b0d2b51456f4287f342. My command to run the build is

```
../build --mode=gcc-10.3.0 --arch=x86_64 --buildroot=/c/mingw-builds/BuildRoot --update-sources --exceptions=seh --threads=posix --enable-languages=c++ --jobs=48 --rt-version=v8
```

The output is

```
-> Checking OS bitness... 64-bit
-> Checking OS type... MINGW32_NT-10.0-18363
-> Checking for installed packages... done
-> x86_64 toolchain
--> Toolchain installed.
-> start building x86_64-10.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v8 with "c++" languages supported
-> libiconv
--> Delete corrupted download... done
--> download libiconv-1.16.tar.gz...
error 1
```

A file `src/MARKERS/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz-download.log` is created which has the following content:

```
--2021-04-12 12:15:04--  https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz
Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
```

Has anyone encountered the same issue? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been something wrong with my SSL certificates. I also have not been able to use `pacman` anymore. My attempts to fix the installation have failed, therefore I have reinstalled `msys2`. Now it works like a charm.